# Unhandled exception in callback

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an Android app where I need to connect to BLE Medical device( here Blood Pressure) and transfer the measured BP. I am upgrading the code .i.e., I have bluetooth 2.0 code which connects to the BP device successfully, writes and reads the values from the device successfully.

But in BLE, I am successfully able to write the value (Here BP device requires a specific value to be written for starting measuring of values) and when I am trying to enable Notifications I am getting Null pointer Exception.

Code for writeCharacteristic method:

```
public boolean writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt) throws InterruptedException {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null ){
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return false;
        }
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null ){
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothGatt not initialized");
            return false;
        }
        //BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR);
        BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(MY_UUID);
        if (Service == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "Service not found!");
            return false;
        }
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = Service.getCharacteristic(MY_UUID_CHARACTERISTIC);
        if (characteristic == null){
            Log.e(TAG, "Characteristic not found!");
            return false;
        }
        //int counter = 3;
        boolean status = false;
        byte[] value = {(byte)0x0A};

        characteristic.setValue(value);
        //Enable local notifications
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
        //Enabled remote notifications
        BluetoothGattDescriptor desc = characteristic.getDescriptor(CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR);
        desc.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(desc);

        status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
        Log.e(TAG, "Service :"+status);
        return status;
    }
```

Log:-

```
11-01 23:39:32.289    1220-1255/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/BluetoothGatt﹕ setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0000fff2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
11-01 23:39:32.289    1220-1220/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
11-01 23:39:32.289    1220-1255/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 W/BluetoothGatt﹕ Unhandled exception in callback
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4.PollingTest$3.writeCharacteristic(PollingTest.java:451)
            at com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4.PollingTest$3.onServicesDiscovered(PollingTest.java:359)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onSearchComplete(BluetoothGatt.java:299)
            at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:215)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-01 23:39:32.369    1220-1220/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
11-01 23:39:32.369    1220-1220/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
11-01 23:39:32.369    1220-1220/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 48
11-01 23:39:32.369    1220-1220/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 48
11-01 23:39:43.239    1220-1255/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/BluetoothGatt﹕ onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=5 device=8C:DE:52:2C:65:B2
11-01 23:39:43.239    1220-1255/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/Tag﹕ Connection State Change: 0 -> Disconnected
11-01 23:39:43.239    1220-1255/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/Tag﹕ Connection State Change: 0 -> Disconnected
11-01 23:39:43.239    1220-1255/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 W/BluetoothGatt﹕ Unhandled exception in callback
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7099)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17449)
            at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9749)
            at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:6298)
            at android.app.Dialog.hide(Dialog.java:302)
            at com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4.PollingTest$3.onConnectionStateChange(PollingTest.java:322)
            at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onClientConnectionState(BluetoothGatt.java:172)
            at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:71)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-01 23:41:32.579    1220-1220/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
11-01 23:41:32.589    1220-1220/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/BluetoothGatt﹕ close()
11-01 23:41:32.589    1220-1220/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 D/BluetoothGatt﹕ unregisterApp() - mClientIf=5
```

---

I am trying to enable notifications for `public UUID CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");`. Is there problem with this UUID or is there something else wrong with my code. Please help me. I am getting NullPointer Exception

Thank You People.

EDIT:

writeCharacterisitic is called from onServiceDiscovered()

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        //mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Enabling Sensors..."));
        /*
         * With services discovered, we are going to reset our state machine and start
         * working through the sensors we need to enable
         */
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            try {
                servicesList = gatt.getServices();
                for (BluetoothGattService service : servicesList) {
                    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
                }
                writeCharacteristic(gatt);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }
```

Comment: From where are you calling writeCharacteristic() method ,Are you calling it inside a thread

Comment: Updated my question. No I am not calling it from seperate thread I guess. I am not sure how to do it. Does that affect callback method?

Comment: You have thread related problem in your code ,you are calling your code  from wrong thread ,You need to identify calling thread first and post relevant information to another thread (it may be UI Thread) .

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with this one:

```
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        //mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(null, MSG_PROGRESS, "Enabling Sensors..."));
        /*
         * With services discovered, we are going to reset our state machine and start
         * working through the sensors we need to enable
         */
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            try {
                servicesList = gatt.getServices();
                for (BluetoothGattService service : servicesList) {
                    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
                }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                writeCharacteristic(gatt);
            }
        });

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Changed to the above code. There was error to make gatt variable final which I changed and the getting fatal error. Log:- `14400-14400/com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4, PID: 14400
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4.PollingTest$3.writeCharacteristic(PollingTest.java:416)at com.example.sagarch.bluetooth_test_4.PollingTest$3$1.run(PollingTest.java:351)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)`
Please help me